# is it possible to have more than one class assigned to an html element?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to assign more than one class to an html element? For example: `<div class="test" class="testing"></div>`? Does the same thing work for IDs?

Comment: Thanks worked! Post an answer and I'll choose as best! Does the same thing work for id attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You use one `class` attribute and separate the class names by spaces

```
<div class="test testing"></div>
```

[From the HTML5 spec:](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes)

> The [`class`] attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just seperate them with a space

Answer (score 1):

yes you can add more than one classes add a space between them

```
<div class="test testing"></div>
```

but you cannot add more than one `id`, `id` should be only one and cannot be repeated in that same page

```
<div id="test"></div>
```